# Sql Server Management Studio 2014 crashes during mouse scrolling

Tags: sql-server, ssms

**Error 1:**

- System

  - Provider

    [ Name]  .NET Runtime
  - EventID 1026

    [ Qualifiers]  0

    Level 2

    Task 0

    Keywords 0x80000000000000
  - TimeCreated

    [ SystemTime]  2016-01-04T09:00:53.000000000Z

    EventRecordID 6854

    Channel Application

    Security
- EventData

  Application: Ssms.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.ArgumentException Stack: at System.Buffer.BlockCopy(System.Array, Int32, System.Array, Int32, Int32) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.FileStreamReader.ReadOne[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Int64, Boolean, Int32, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.SpecialDataType ByRef, Int32 ByRef) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.FileStreamReader.ReadInt32(Int64, Boolean, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.SpecialDataType ByRef, Int32 ByRef) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.SequentialReadColumn(Int32, Boolean) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.GetCellDataFromFileInternal(Int64, Int32, Boolean) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.GetCellData(Int64, Int32) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.StorageViewBase.GetCellDataAsStringInternal(Int64, Int32) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.GetCellDataAsString(Int64, Int32) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.ResultBindingList.GetValue(Int32, Int32) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.QueryResultControl.DataGridView_CellValueNeeded(System.Object, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueNeeded(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueNeeded(Int32, Int32) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetValue(Int32) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell.GetPreferredSize(System.Drawing.Graphics, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle, Int32, System.Drawing.Size) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetPreferredWidth(Int32, Int32) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.OnCellDataAreaMouseEnterInternal(Int32) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.OnMouseMoveInternal(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.UpdateMouseEnteredCell(HitTestInfo, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef) at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef) at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DTDataGridView.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef) at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef) at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef) at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

**Error 2:**

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  Application Error

  - EventID 1000

  [ Qualifiers]  0

  Level 2

  Task 100

  Keywords 0x80000000000000

  - TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2016-01-04T09:00:53.000000000Z

  EventRecordID 6855

  Channel Application

  Security
- EventData

  Ssms.exe 
  2014.120.2000.8 
  5306c06d 
  KERNELBASE.dll 
  10.0.10240.16384 
  559f3b2a 
  e0434352 
  000b3e28 
  1128 
  01d146cdd1042894 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe 
  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll 
  ad7f1b83-9530-4557-b749-944fb004f9ad

Comment: This is during `Edit Top 200 Rows` on a table.

Comment: Please install `SP1`...

Comment: Thanks, I thing it worked!

Comment: You are welcome... :)

Answer (score 2):

Installing SP1 should fix the problem.